# Class template argument deduction doesn't work as function template argument deduction

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, template-argument-deduction, class-template

I am learning about class template argument deduction and I could not understand why statement `C<> c(5);`  fails unlike the call `func<>(5)` . I mean I expected that in the statement `C<> c(5);`, T should have been deduced to `int` but to my surprise the program generated an error saying `error: wrong number of template arguments (0, should be 1)`.

```
template<typename T>
void func(T t)
{
   
}
template<typename T>
struct C
{
    C(T t)
    {
       
    }
};

int main()
{
    func<>(5);  //works as expected with T = int
   
   
    C<> c(5);  //why this fails? I mean why T is not being deduced from the argument 5's type?
   
    C   b(5);  //works as expected with T = int
}
```

So I want to know why does the statement `C<> c(5);` fail to compile.

Answer (score 1):

Because class template argument deduction(CTAD) doesn't work if/when you explicitly use/specify the template argument list `<>` even if it is empty!

This can be seen from [CTAD's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#Notes) which states:

> **Notes**
>
> Class template argument deduction is only **performed if no template argument list is present. If a template argument list is specified, deduction does not take place.**

(emphasis mine)

This means that since you've explicitly specified the template argument list `<>`, deduction won't happen here.